# Add a W3-compliant javascript external link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, w3c-validation

I'd like to show some text only if javascript is enabled, and that text includes a link. However, this is apparently not W3-compliant and I get the following errors:

- Line 11, Column 117: document type does not allow element "a" here

- Line 11, Column 131: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

- Line 11, Column 148: end tag for "a" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified


My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
    <link href="css/inia.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <p class="small"><script type="text/javascript">document.write('An <a class="external" href="http:\/\/example.com\/">external link<\/a>.');</script></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm only starting javascript, so any help would be appreciated, including jquery solutions. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="js" style="display:none">
        <a class="external" href="http://example.com/">external link</a>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("js").style["display"] = "block";
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea. (I did need to add a type to the script tag but otherwise it was fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of XHTML where [script elements do not automatically contain CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) but since you serve the XHTML as text/html (claiming that it is HTML and not XHTML) [browsers think they do](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

The advice on the links above (read both!) will solve the validity problem. I would switch to HTML 4.01 Strict or HTML 5 instead of jumping through the hoops of writing to write something that is (aside from the Doctype) both HTML and XHTML).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It seems like I should familiarize myself with XHTML vs HTML. I took up a project knowing little web programming (so I'm mostly self taught) and since I learned with the validator (and could get things to validate) I never really questioned the doctype. Anyway, it looks like switching it to HTML 4.01 strict (with a few shorttag fixes) solves the problem, but the solution by Shaz works as well...